# Inserting timetamp values in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, timestamp, sqlplus

I created two column in my Table with data type as TimeStamp with these command

```
ALTER TABLE TOY_STORE ADD STORE_OPENING_TIME TIMESTAMP;
ALTER TABLE TOY_STORE ADD STORE_CLOSING_TIME TIMESTAMP;
```

Also i added a condition with below command

```
alter table toy_store ADD CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM store_opening_time) > 8 || NULL);
alter table toy_store ADD CHECK (EXTRACT(HOUR FROM store_closing_time) < 22 || NULL);
```

Now the issue is when i tried to enter values by using below command it works perfectly

```
INSERT INTO TOY_STORE VALUES(TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-01 09:00:12.742000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),NULL);
```

but I cannot enter closing time as when i try to enter value with below command

```
INSERT INTO TOY_STORE VALUES(TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-01 09:00:12.742000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-04-01 18:00:00.000000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));
```

I get Error in SQL PLUS as `ORA-02290: check constraint (E1245050.SYS_C00277734) violated`.
Since i have set constraint as <22 but dont know why i am getting error.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: error is 
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (E1245050.SYS_C00277734) violated

Comment: So the problem is not the way you insert the timestamp value; you have to check what is that constraint and why you are violating it (for example, inserting null in a not null field, ...)

Comment: Please check the constraint i added.I have updated my question with constraint statement

Comment: The constraint says you need hour > 8, you are inserting 6

Comment: Have you previously added constraints with earlier time limits (or completely different checks)? Because you haven't named your constraint it's hard to see what it's actually complaining about - you just know it's violating **a** constraint, not necessarily the one you show. Look in `user_constraints` and related views to see all the constraints you have on this table, and se what `SYS_C00277734` is actually checking. (What do you think `||NULL` is doing? `||` is concatenation, not logical OR).

Comment: Both of the constraints you show are for `store_opening_time`; have you added some for `store_closing_time` too? Can you add the result of `select constraint_name, search_condition from user_constraints where table_name = 'TOY_STORE';` to the question?

Comment: Sorry i have added constraint condition to closing time (updated the question) in case of closing time it is accepting null value as well as value 1 to 9 but when i use 10 or more in 'HH' format it gives error

Comment: What you've shown does not generate that error, but it really isn't clear if that's what you are actually running. Please add the output of the query from my last comment to the question, so we can see what constraints you really have,

Comment: when i run query as select STORE_CLOSING_TIME FROM TOY_STORE;
I get output as STORE_CLOSING_TIME   01-APR-14 09.00.00.000000 AM

Comment: i get above output as statement having time as 9 or less then it is accepted and saved but when i pass time as 10 or more then it  shows error

Comment: What does the query against `user_constraints` show? Please add that to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109034/discussion-between-er-naved-ali-and-alex-poole).